# Unicode character "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA" is rendered as "White vertical rectangle" in c++ and GLStudio

Tags: c++, opengl, unicode

Programming language: `C++`, Renderer: `GLStudio`.

I want to render Unicode Character `'GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA' (U+0394)` as in: `ΔP`

The code is:

```
sprintf(somebuffer,"%cP",'\u0394');
```

however the result is WHITE VERTICAL RECTANGLE' (U+25AF) as below:

```
▯P
```

Here is the reference I used: [http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25af/index.htm](http://unicodes)

Obviously there is a unicode mapping issue on the renderer but I could not pinpoint it exactly so wanted to try my chances in SO before trying to draw an actual opengl triangle as a workaround. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A `char` in C++ is one byte, and `%c` says you're passing a `char`.

Comment: @chris: That`s a very good point. I tried to render it as a string as well. Then it gave a totally different unicode character.

Comment: You have used `%c`, which with `sprint` is a placeholder for a single `char` value. You're passing it `\u394`, which with most C++ implementation will not be a single byte, i.e. not of type `char`. What you need to do depends on what the relevant GLStudio function requires. If it wants a wide string, pass it that. If wants an UTF-8 encoded narrow string, pass it that.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, why don't you use `std::string` and `std::ostringstream` for formatting strings?

Comment: Or why use formatting at all? Why not simply do `strcpy(somebuffer, "\u0394P")` (to continue with the C functions)?

Comment: Friends, thanks for awesome comments. I am updating someone else`s code so I have to "kinda" use sprintf. But will definitely fix the character (1 byte) issue.

Comment: I am trying the suggestions. Why did the question get down-vote? Please help me improve the question if not in good shape. Thanks.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the renderer has access to the font file at runtime or, in the case of some rendering engines, at build time so it can generate the correct glyphs as textures. It depends what mode you are generating text in what you need to worry about -- does it generate them on the fly or "bake" text into textures and then reference those textures, either as a whole or as individual glyphs within the texture? The different modes have different trade-offs in terms of runtime performance and texture overhead, so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

This entirely depends on the encoding expected by the renderer. There's a good chance it expects or supports UTF-8:

```
sprintf(somebuffer, u8"\u0394P");
```

This forms the string `<capital delta><P>` encoded in UTF-8 and writes it to the buffer (without checking size or using a more suitable C function like `strncpy`). It's then up to the renderer to take those bytes and render them how you expect.

What's going on currently is very likely passing an `int` argument in place of the `%c` placeholder that expects a `char`. I would imagine that while undefined behaviour, it's taking the first byte and treating that as a `char`.